# ENOTFOUND when running npm install

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, npm-install

I am trying to install dependencies for a project with this project.json file:

```
{
  "name": "Pizza",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "NIT Project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "TheSmokingGnu",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "basil.js": "^0.4.3",
    "brfs": "^1.4.3",
    "ejs": "^2.4.1",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-browserify": "^4.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1"
  }
}
```

I just cd into directory(or use webshtorm's console for that), and run npm install:

```
npm install
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/ejs failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ip ip:80
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help
```

I am using Windows 10 (installed just yesterday), with system firewall turned off. I did not have any intention to use proxys, my config list looks like that:

```
>npm config list
; cli configs
metrics-registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/5.5.1 node/v8.9.1 win32 x64"

; userconfig C:\Users\taras\.npmrc
http-proxy = "http://username:password@ip:port"
https-proxy = "http://username:password@ip/:port"
registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
strict-ssl = false

; builtin config undefined
prefix = "C:\\Users\\taras\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"

; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
; cwd = D:\Downloads\JS-Pizza-master\JS-Pizza-master
; HOME = C:\Users\taras
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
```

Finally, my error log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install' ]
2 info using npm@5.5.1
3 info using node@v8.9.1
4 verbose npm-session 9d19f4920a39031f
5 silly install runPreinstallTopLevelLifecycles
6 silly preinstall Pizza@1.0.0
7 info lifecycle Pizza@1.0.0~preinstall: Pizza@1.0.0
8 silly install loadCurrentTree
9 silly install readLocalPackageData
10 silly install loadIdealTree
11 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
12 silly install loadShrinkwrap
13 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
14 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for grunt@^0.4.5 request to http://registry.npmjs.org/grunt failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ip ip:80
15 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for ejs@^2.4.1 request to http://registry.npmjs.org/ejs failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ip ip:80
16 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for brfs@^1.4.3 request to http://registry.npmjs.org/brfs failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ip ip:80
17 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for basil.js@^0.4.3 request to http://registry.npmjs.org/basil.js failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ip ip:80
18 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for grunt-contrib-watch@^0.6.1 request to http://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-watch failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ip ip:80
19 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for grunt-browserify@^4.0.1 request to http://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-browserify failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ip ip:80
20 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for basil.js@^0.4.3 request to http://registry.npmjs.org/basil.js failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ip ip:80
21 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for brfs@^1.4.3 request to http://registry.npmjs.org/brfs failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ip ip:80
22 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for ejs@^2.4.1 request to http://registry.npmjs.org/ejs failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ip ip:80
23 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for grunt@^0.4.5 request to http://registry.npmjs.org/grunt failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ip ip:80
24 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for grunt-browserify@^4.0.1 request to http://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-browserify failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ip ip:80
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for grunt-contrib-watch@^0.6.1 request to http://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-watch failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ip ip:80
26 verbose type system
27 verbose stack FetchError: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/basil.js failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ip ip:80
27 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.req.on.err (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:68:14)
27 verbose stack     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
27 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
27 verbose stack     at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
27 verbose stack     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
27 verbose stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
27 verbose stack     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
27 verbose stack     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
27 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
28 verbose cwd D:\Downloads\JS-Pizza-master\JS-Pizza-master
29 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299
30 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
31 verbose node v8.9.1
32 verbose npm  v5.5.1
33 error code ENOTFOUND
34 error errno ENOTFOUND
35 error network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/basil.js failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ip ip:80
36 error network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
36 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
36 error network
36 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
36 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
37 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Your user config file looks a little odd to me (if you don't want to use a proxy): `http-proxy: "http://username:password@ip:port"`. As a quick test, I'd remove the **C:\Users\taras\.npmrc** file (or just rename to `ignore.npmrc`) and re-do the **npm install**.

Comment: That helped, thank you. I recall running one set proxy command, but i have uninstalled node and npm after that. Guess the settings stay.

Comment: Perfect. If I add an anser, can you check it "accepted"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your user config file looks like you have some sort of proxy configured:

```
; userconfig C:\Users\taras\.npmrc
http-proxy = "http://username:password@ip:port"
https-proxy = "http://username:password@ip/:port"
registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
strict-ssl = false
```

If you don't intend to use a proxy, I'd remove the **C:\Users\taras.npmrc** and re-do **npm install**.

*Update:* As the config files is stored in the user directory, it will remain unchanged, when you e.g. update npm.

Comment: @Ali  If you need support with your error, take the time to post a full question telling us what you try to do and what is not working. There are lot's of folks on SO to support you ;)

Comment: I am trying npm install but getting that ENOTFOUND error, I don't know what values I need to put for http-proxy, I have checked there is no proxy configured, so how can I get those values?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because the proxy do not stand for https. What I do is clear the proxy content of ~/.npmrc, or use

```js
npm config delete proxy
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and I resolved this issue by hitting the following command:

```
1. npm config delete registry-name
```

You can replace **registry-name** with you actual registry.

```
2. npm config delete registry
3. npm config delete @registry
```